# How to Make HTML Form Drop-Down List Items Redirect

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a pretty basic website as a beginning web developer. I'm wondering how you can take a value from a drop-down list form in HTML, click the submit button, and have it redirect you to a new page, depending on what was chosen. Each month should be a new webpage. Here's the code:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <p>Month</p>
    <select name="months">
        <option value="march2015">March, 2015</option>
        <option value="april2015">April, 2015</option>
        <option value="may2015">May, 2015</option>
        <option value="june2015">June, 2015</option>
        <option value="july2015">July, 2015</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm a little unclear about what to put for the "action" attribute. I'm not using a web hosting service, I'm just viewing the file in my browser.

Comment: You can't do that with pure CSS and HTML. Use JS/jQuery to update `form` action with `select` value

Comment: Use JS getAttribute when Select on change Event then : window.location.href='yourURL.com/value';

Comment: Just add your page URL in action, for example: `action="http://example.com/page.php"` when you hit submit you will be redirect to: `http://example.com/page.php?months=march2015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some Javascript for that.

Update your HTML like this:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="get">
    (...)
    <select name="months" onchange="update_action(this)">
        (...)
    </select>
        (...)
</form>
```

And attach via `<script />` tag file with following code:

**JS (script.js)**

```
var update_action = function(obj) {
    var val = obj.value;
    var url = /* Setup your URL here. */;

    document.querySelector('#form').setAttribute('action', url);
};
```

Should work :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I'm still very new to JS, would you mind explaining that code a little more? I can't figure out how to apply it to my code.

Comment: Yeah, sure. In line 3 (HTML) there's a attribute onchange="..." which tells Javascript tu run this function after any option will be selected. Then, in JS you have this function and what it does is: get the value of the select (content of `value` attribute in selected `<option />`), then set the url based on selected value, and then replace the content of `action` attribute of the form.

Comment: Thanks again. How would I alter the code to redirect to different webpages for different selections?

Comment: Just use `if-else` or `switch-case` to build your url depending on the selected value.